# Are there $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{a + b}{a + b + c + d} < \frac{a}{a + c} < \frac{b}{b + d}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, inequality, data-mining

Consider the following $2 \times 2$ contingency table:
\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
 & C & \overline C & \Sigma \\ \hline
V & 4000 & 3500 & 7500 \\
\overline V & 2000 & 500 & 2500 \\ \hline
\Sigma & 6000 & 4000 & 10000
\end{array}

In data mining, we informally say that the association rule $C \to V$ is *misleading*. We could justify this by observing that:
$$
\Pr[V \mid C] = \frac{4000}{6000} = 0.\overline{6} < 0.75 = \frac{7500}{10000} = \Pr[V]
$$
Alternatively, we could justify this by observing that:
$$
\Pr[V \mid C] = \frac{4000}{6000} = 0.\overline{6} < 0.875 = \frac{3500}{4000} = \Pr[V \mid \overline C]
$$
I'm trying to figure out which justification is more compelling. When I change the numbers in the contingency table, both inequalities always seem to be simultaneously satisfied. I can't seem to make one inequality true and the other false.

---

More generally, consider the contingency table:

\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
 & C & \overline C & \Sigma \\ \hline
V & a & b & a+b \\
\overline V & c & d & c + d\\ \hline
\Sigma & a + c & b + d & a + b + c + d
\end{array}

> **Question:** Do there exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb N$ such that either one of the following two inequalities are satisfied:
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{a + b}{a + b + c + d} &< \frac{a}{a + c} < \frac{b}{b + d} \tag{1} \\
> \frac{b}{b + d} &< \frac{a}{a + c} < \frac{a + b}{a + b + c + d} \tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In general, for $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb N$ with $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$, $$\frac{a}{b} <\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}{d}.$$
**Proof**: The left inequality is equivalent to $$a(b+d) < b(a+c) \iff ad < bc \iff \frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}.$$ Likewise for the right inequality.

Comment: That's true for all positive reals.  You have shown for positive reals $p, q, r, s$, $$\dfrac p q < \dfrac r s \iff \dfrac p q < \dfrac {p+r}{q+s} < \dfrac r s$$

Now take $p = a, r = b, q = a+c, s = b+d$.

Comment: @Macavity Of course. Indeed I could change $\Bbb N$ to any ordered field. But why include this generality if it's irrelevant?

Comment: I up voted your answer because it was already complete.  Adding any easy generalisation usually helps interested people explore a bit more on their own. However your generalisation is off - it does not work for **all** ordered fields, you may need to think more on that.  for e.g. wont work for all reals.

Comment: @Macavity Sorry, I spoke too quickly. I meant the positive part of any ordered field.

Answer (score 1):

None of the two double-inequalities can hold for any $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R^+$.

$$\frac{a + b}{a + b + c + d} < \frac{a}{a + c} \iff (a+b)(a+c)<a(a+b+c+d)$$

$$\iff \frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}$$

The same way you get:

$$ \frac{a}{a+c} < \frac{b}{b + d} \iff \frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$$

The two inequalities contradict each other.

Use the same method for the other double-inequality.